# Does $2^X=2^Y\Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$ imply the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

**The Generalized Continuum Hypothesis** can be stated as $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$. We know that GCH implies AC (Jech, *The Axiom of Choice*, Theorem 9.1 p.133).

In fact, a relatively weak formulation: $|X|\le|Y|< 2^X\implies |X|=|Y|$ would already imply the axiom of choice, although in this case the proof is slightly longer. [Note: in Herrlich's book he refers to **GCH** stated above as "The Aleph Hypothesis" and the weak formulation is called GCH]

GCH itself is independent of the axiom of choice, we can have the axiom of choice and power sets can grow wildly, or just "a little bit". We can have the continuum function to be injective, but the continuum hypothesis can fail on a proper class of cardinals (for example $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$ for regular cardinals).

Let **ICF** (Injective Continuum Function) be the assertion: $$2^X=2^Y\implies |X|=|Y|.$$

**Question:** Assuming ZF+ICF, can we deduce AC?

(I looked around Equivalents of the Axiom of Choice, but couldn't find much. It is possible that I missed this, though.)

---

**Edits:**

1. In an exercise in Jech he states that if there exists an infinite Dedekind-finite cardinal, then ICF does not hold. From the assumption that it holds we can deduce that there are no infinite D-finite sets.
2. Note that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a surjection then $A\subseteq Y\mapsto f^{-1}(A)$ is an injection from $P(Y)$ into $P(X)$. This means that **ICF** implies the [Dual Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem) theorem:

   Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have surjections from one onto the other, then there are injections between their power-sets therefore $2^X=2^Y$ and thus $|X|=|Y|$.
3. We shall abbreviate Goldstern's variant of ICF as **Homomorphic Continuum Function**, or **HCF**: $$2^X\leq 2^Y\implies |X|\leq|Y|$$
   One major observation is that HCF implies *The Partition Principle* (PP), which states that $A$ can be mapped onto $B$ (or $B$ is empty) if and only if $B$ can be injected into $A$. This principle is quite an open choice principle, and it is unknown whether or not it implies AC in ZF.

   To see that HCF implies PP, we observe the following: if $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective then the preimage map is an injection from $2^B$ into $2^A$, i.e. $2^B\leq 2^A$, from HCF it follows that $B\leq A$, i.e. there is $g\colon B\to A$ injective.

Comment: The implication from $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ to AC is not quite trivial. It is a starred exercise in Kunen's book (III.9).  There are two reasons why I call it non-trivial: The axiom of foundation seems to be necessary; and the limit step is not as trivial as it may appear to the naive reader. 

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Goldstern, because I've seen too many students give the standard false proof of "If power sets of well-orderable sets are well-orderable then AC holds," even after being warned that there is a standard false proof.

Comment: Andreas, Goldstern: I thought it over and you both were right. The transfinite induction argument cannot hold because we cannot assure that the union of well ordered families of well ordered sets is well orderable. I gave reference to the proof, which is not *very* hard but indeed less trivial than I'd expected.

Comment: A reasonable (possibly easier) variant of your question: Does $\forall X,Y:( 2^X\le 2^Y \Rightarrow X \le Y) $ imply AC? 

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17152/when-2a-2b-implies-ab-a-b-cardinals


Comment: Steve, yes somewhat relevant but under choice the question I ask is moot. In ZFC everything implies AC :-)

Comment: I think that the name "weak ICF" is misleading because it is in fact the stronger assertion (unless ICF itself implies choice), if anyone got a suggestion for a better name I'm open to hear it.

Comment: Asaf, I was about to point out the same Maybe "strong ICF"?

Comment: Andres, but strong ICF sounds like the injectivity is strengthened, where it is in fact weakened.

Comment: It is still more accurate. 

Comment: Andres, not only I think the name is better we have that H precedes I in the alphabet, so it is a stronger letter! Clearly HCF is stronger than ICF! :-)

Comment: @Goldstern You say the axiom of foundation seems to be necessary to prove GCH implies AC. I'm not seeing that myself; here is a proof that I wrote up in the nLab, based on a reading of an article by Leonard Gillman in the Amer. Math. Monthly: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hartogs+number#gch_implies_ac

Comment: @Todd: For the formulation with aleph numbers, that's easy: consider ZFC+Atoms, but instead of weakening Extensionality, use Quine atom's (x={x}) and remove Foundation. Now violate choice by any means necessary, then no pure sets are affected. If GCH held in the outer model, it will hold in the permutation model. (By the way, when looking for X such that X+X=X and Y embeds into X, taking X=Y x N works as well.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Thanks; that sounds interesting (although I'm afraid it's too compressed for me to follow easily). I'm asking because the proof I linked to is easily formulated in a "structural" or non-membership based set theory like ETCS where Foundation doesn't even come up, so it's hard for me to understand why it would be relevant. So if you will forgive me for saying so, I guess it must be a peculiarity of ZF (-: . It may be naive to ask, but can you point to a spot in the proof I linked to where Foundation would be needed to fully justify it in ZF?

Comment: @Todd: Martin (Goldstern)'s comment was about the formulation in terms of aleph numbers. I think that the proof of the seemingly-weaker-formulation is indeed robust without foundation, but the equivalence between them will require Foundation. But then again, the aleph numbers don't really come out naturally in ETCS.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks again; that's helpful. You're right that in ETCS we don't talk about von Neumann style ordinals and cardinals, although we of course perform transfinite induction arguments along well-ordered sets, which is mostly what ordinary mathematicians use them for. :-)

Comment: @Todd: It's your loss. I make a great cocktails with supercompact cardinals. I strongly recommend "supercompact gin tonic" or at least "strong bourbon on ice". ;)

Comment: @AsafKaragila At the risk of being "too chatty" -- I'm with you on strong bourbon on the rocks. :-)

Answer (score 21):

Here is a little progress towards AC.

**Theorem.**
 ICF implies the dual Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein
theorem, that is $X$ surjects onto $Y$ and $Y$ surjects onto $X$,
then they are bijective.

Proof. You explain this in the edit to the question. If
$X\twoheadrightarrow Y$, then $2^Y\leq 2^X$ by taking pre-images,
and so if also $Y\twoheadrightarrow X$, then $2^X\leq 2^Y$ and so
$X\sim Y$ by ICF. QED

**Theorem.** ICF implies that there are no infinite D-finite
sets.

Proof. (This is a solution to the exercise that you mention.) If $A$ is infinite and
Dedekind-finite, then let $B$ be the set of all finite
non-repeating finite sequences from $A$. This is also D-finite,
since a countably infinite subset of $B$ easily gives rise to a
countably infinite subset of $A$. But meanwhile, $B$ surjects onto
$B+1$, since we can map the empty sequence to the new point, and
apply the shift map to chop off the first element of any sequence.
So $B$ and $B+1$ surject onto each other, and so by the dual
Cantor-Schöder-Bernstein result, they are bijective,
contradicting the fact that $B$ is D-finite. QED

Here is the new part:

**Theorem.** ICF implies that $\kappa^+$ injects into
$2^\kappa$ for every ordinal $\kappa$.

Proof. We may assume $\kappa$ is infinite. Notice that
$2^{\kappa^2}$ surjects onto $\kappa^+$, since every
$\alpha<\kappa$ is coded by a relation on $\kappa$. Since
$\kappa^2\sim\kappa$, this means
$2^\kappa\twoheadrightarrow\kappa^+$ and consequently
$2^{\kappa^+}\leq 2^{2^\kappa}$, by taking pre-images. It follows that
$2^{2^\kappa}=2^{2^\kappa}\cdot 2^{\kappa^+}=2^{2^\kappa+\kappa^+}$ and
so by ICF we get $2^\kappa+\kappa^+=2^\kappa$, which implies
$\kappa^+\leq 2^\kappa$, as desired. QED

This conclusion already contradicts AD, for example, since AD
implies that there is no $\omega_1$ sequence of distinct reals,
which violates the conclusion when $\kappa=\omega$. In particular,
this shows that ICF implies $\neg$AD, and so in every AD model, there are sets of different cardinalities, whose power sets are equinumerous.

Comment: Indeed. It is simple to see that in ZF+AD $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$ (and for many many more ordinals) so ICF fails bad. Furthermore every cardinal below $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ which is a quotient of $\mathbb R$ (read: cardinal of equivalence classes of some relation) will have the same power set as $\mathbb R$ itself. There are *so* many of these as well. But the new part is interesting indeed!

Comment: Joel, it may be worth pointing out that the non-existence of infinite D-finite sets already follows from dual Schroeder-Bernstein.

Comment: Joel, your answer inspired me to the recent edit. I think it's a strong hint that HCF might imply AC (although it is not provable from it).

Comment: Yes, Andres, my argument shows indeed that the dual CSB theorem implies there are no D-finite infinite sets, since I use only dual CSB and not ICF. 

Comment: The third theorem also follows from dual CSB using surjections $2^\kappa \to 2^{\kappa + \kappa} \to 2^\kappa \times 2^\kappa \to 2^\kappa \times \kappa^+ \to 2^\kappa$.

Comment: @Asaf: In ZF + AD, $2^\omega \ne 2^{\omega_1}$. The coding lemma gives a surjection, but there cannot be an injection (just look at singleton subsets of $\omega_1$.)

Comment: Trevor, indeed, under AD we have $2^\omega\neq 2^{\omega_1}$, since $\omega_1$ does not inject into $2^\omega$, but since under AD those power sets surject onto each other, we get $2^{2^\omega}=2^{2^{\omega_1}}$ via pre-images. 

Comment: Ugh, yes. Trevor you are absolutely correct. I was thinking about $\leq^\ast$ rather than $\leq$, Joel gave the correct argument I was aiming for.

Comment: Joel: And the argument I knew was much more elaborate, too. This is nice. 

Comment: Can you explain to me how you got $\kappa^+ \le^* 2^{\kappa^2}$? What do you mean codes there? Also, don't you need choice for $\kappa^2\sim\kappa$?

Comment: @Holo Every ordinal less than $\kappa^+$ is the order type of a relation on $\kappa$; this relation is a subset of $\kappa\times\kappa$. Thus, $\kappa^+\leq^* 2^{\kappa^2}$. This does not seem to require $\kappa^2\sim \kappa$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins thanks!, about the second part, you used that fact the next line, you can use this fact because $\kappa$ is already well ordered?

Comment: Yes, that's right.