# "Matryoshka" sets and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following two very similar statements in ${\sf ZF}$:

> (Mat_1) There is a set $A$ a map $\alpha: \omega \to {\cal P}(A)$ such that for all $n\in \omega$ we have $\alpha(n+1) \subseteq \alpha(n)$, and there is *no* **injective** map from $\alpha(n)$ into $\alpha(n+1)$.

and

> (Mat_2) There is a set $A$ a map $\alpha: \omega \to {\cal P}(A)$ such that for all $n\in \omega$ we have $\alpha(n+1) \subseteq \alpha(n)$, and there is *no* **surjective** map from $\alpha(n+1)$ onto $\alpha(n)$.

In both settings we have a sequence of subsets of a ground set $A$ getting smaller and smaller - reminscent of [Matryoshka dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

Note that neither statement is compatible with the Axiom of Choice ${\sf (AC})$ since the $\{|\alpha(n)|: n\in \omega\}$ would be an infinite strictly descending sequence in the cardinal $|A|$, contradicting the fact that $|A|$ is well-ordered.

Note the following:

**Fact.** In ${\sf ZF}$, if $A, B$ are non-empty sets and $f:A\to B$ is an injection, then there is a surjection $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f$ is the identity on $A$.

From this we get that (Mat_2) implies (Mat_1).

Are (Mat_1) and (Mat_2) equivalent in ${\sf ZF}$? Does one of $\neg$(Mat_1) and $\neg$(Mat_2) imply ${\sf (AC)}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634372/127263

Comment: It's very easy to find examples of sequences witnessing (1) but not (2), but it's a lot harder to show that there are no other sequences.

Comment: I've just realized there is a subtle difference between this question and the one I linked above - essentially, in this question, you need to not only have a descending sequence of cardinals, but you also need to *choose* the representatives of cardinalities. Because of this it is for instance not immediate that the negation of Mat_1 implies there are no infinite Dedekind-finite cardinals (while it would be clear if we looked at cardinals themselves).

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu for both the link and your additional comment

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila for your comment; sorry for being slow, can you give me a hint? I am especially interested in your "uniqueness" remark

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308095/can-we-have-an-infinite-sequence-of-decreasing-cardinality-all-terms-of-which-ha/ and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308030/are-there-known-examples-of-sets-whose-power-set-is-equal-in-size-to-power-set-o

Comment: Thanks! So $\neg$(Mat_1) is stronger than $\neg$(Mat_2), and is it known about any implication of these to the Partition Principle, or the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem?

Comment: Again, you're making the wrong inference. All it shows is that there are witnesses for Mat₁ which are not witnesses for Mat₂. But the statement of both of the Mat's is existential. It quantifies over all sequences in the universe.

Comment: Seems I have to brush up on my negation / contraposition handling :)