# Is $2^\mathfrak{m}<2^\mathfrak{n}\Rightarrow\mathfrak{m}<\mathfrak{n}$ equivalent to the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Note that $2^\mathfrak{m}<2^\mathfrak{n}\Rightarrow\mathfrak{m}<\mathfrak{n}$ follows from the axiom of choice. Is it equivalent to the axiom of choice?

[A similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204).

Remark. Lindenbaum and Tarski assert in ``Communication sur les recherches de la théorie des ensembles'' without proof that $\mathfrak{p}^\mathfrak{m}<\mathfrak{p}^\mathfrak{n}\wedge\mathfrak{p}\neq0\Rightarrow\mathfrak{m}<\mathfrak{n}$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice (see page 186, No. 82). This is not difficult to prove, but I do not know whether the statement for $\mathfrak{p}=2$ is also equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: What's the quantifier on $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}$ in the quoted statement? And on the statement of the question what's the quantifier on $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}$? I guess it means $\forall\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}$, but what are $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}$ supposed to denote? Cardinals (i.e. size of well-orderable sets)?

Comment: @YCor For all cardinals $\mathfrak{p}$, $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$, $\dots$. Here by ``cardinal'' I mean the cardinality of any set (may be non-well-orderable).

Comment: Ah, OK. (I was taught that a cardinal is an ordinal not in bijection with any smaller ordinal, so it's not the same convention.)

Comment: @YCor In the literature, well-ordered cardinals are always be denoted by $\kappa$, $\lambda$, and so on.

Comment: @YCor: You were taught that in the context of ZFC. In the context of ZF it is not helpful to restrict yourself to $\aleph$ numbers if you want to talk about cardinal arithmetic in general.

Comment: This is the type of question that is either deceptively easy once you know a trick; or incredibly hard (which implies the answer may very well be negative; but we do not have any actual tools for constructing counterexamples).

Comment: @AsafKaragila AC wasn't assumed, but indeed this allows to define cardinal as a certain collection of sets. The definition here seems to consider the quotient of the collection of sets by an equivalence relation, which seems more delicate to define properly. Of course in problems such as here, it's not important to make sense of this operation of taking quotient.

Comment: @YCor: Well, that's a shame. Many people stick to this definition quite religiously for some reason, even though it doesn't make any sense. If you want to talk about cardinal arithmetic like that, then in ZF exponentiation does not exist, which is kind of silly. On the other hand, Scott's trick provides us with a very elegant solution as to why the cardinals are themselves sets and why their arithmetic is well-defined. It's almost as shameful as how people insist to not teach symmetric systems and just focus on $L(A)$ and such for the proof that AC is not provable from ZF. But I digress.

Comment: @GuozhenShen: what is the proof of the statement from the paper?

Comment: @Michal: Let $X$ be any non-empty set; $A=X^\omega$ and $\kappa=\aleph(2^A)$ is the Hartogs number of $2^A$. Note that $A^2=A$. Take $\frak p$ to be $2^A$, we get: $$(2^A)^A=2^{A^2}=2^A<2^{A\cdot\kappa}=(2^A)^\kappa,$$ and therefore $A<\kappa$, so $A$ can be well-ordered and therefore $X$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: (The reason the above doesn't generalise to answer the question is that $A^2=A$ implies that $A<A\cdot\kappa$, so there is not enough meat in the statement to deduce that $A<\kappa$.)

Comment: @Asaf: thank you! But I think I am still missing something - why can't you use: $(2^A)^A=2^{A^2}=2^A= (2^A)^1$ to infer $A \approx 1$, i.e.~that $A$ is a singleton?

Comment: @Michal: No, because $=$ is not the same as $<$.

Comment: @Asaf, thanks, I've got it now :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $2^X=2^Y\Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$ imply the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x-2y-rightarrow-x-y-imply-the-axiom-of-choice)

Comment: @AlexM. I don't think that's the same question. It's about $=$ rather than $<$.