# Weak Power Hypothesis with injections instead of bijections

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Let $x,y$ be sets. We use the following notation:

- $x\simeq y$ means that there is a bijection $\varphi:x\to y$, and
- $x\leq y$ means that there is an injection $\iota:x\to y$.

The Weak Power Hypothesis says

> (WPH) Whenever ${\cal P}(x)\simeq {\cal P}(y)$ then $x\simeq y$.

Consider the statement

> (WPH$_\leq$) Whenever ${\cal P}(x) \leq {\cal P}(y)$ then $x\leq y$.

Using the theorem of [Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) we can show in ${\sf (ZF)}$ that (WPH$_\leq$) implies (WPH).

**Question.** In ${\sf (ZF)}$, does (WPH) imply (WPH$_\leq$)?

**Notes.**

1. As Joel David Hawkins notes in the comment section, (WPH) and (WPH$_\leq$) are equivalent in ${\sf (ZFC)}$.
2. There are models of ${\sf (ZFC)}$ in which (WPH) does not hold - but interestingly, it appears to be [open](https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093635502) whether (WPH) implies (AC).

Comment: Who's to say...

Comment: You might mention that in ZFC the two principles are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins, will do.

Comment: As a general advice, never link to your Google search. It may not work the way you expect with other people. Either install one of the browser extensions that cleans out Google search result links, or open the link, then copy-paste. Even more so in the case of an academic paper that has a DOI, it is good practice to just use the DOI link.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila . I found the DOI number, but not the DOI link - but the projecteuclid.org link which I hope, is also acceptable?

Comment: The DOI link to DOI XXX is https://doi.org/XXX .

Comment: Thank you @EmilJeřábek, I modified the link in my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you seen the remarks on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x-2y-rightarrow-x-y-imply-the-axiom-of-choice?