# Does the Weak Power Hypothesis imply the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

If there is a bijection $\varphi:x\to y$ between two sets $x$ and $y$, we use the notation $x\simeq y$. The *Weak Power Hypothesis* is the following statement:

> (WPH) For all sets $x, y$, whenever ${\cal P}(x) \simeq {\cal P}(y)$, then $x\simeq y$.

It appears to be [open](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x-2y-rightarrow-x-y-imply-the-axiom-of-choice) whether (WPH) implies the Axiom of Choice (AC).

Does (WPH) imply the [Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem (BPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem)?

Comment: I would believe that this is open