# Does $\mathfrak{P}(A)\cong\mathfrak{P}(B)$ imply $A\cong B$?

Tags: set-theory

Does $\mathfrak{P}(A)\cong\mathfrak{P}(B)\implies A\cong B$ hold for arbitrary sets $A, B$?

Notation:

- We write $\mathfrak{P}(M)$ to denote the power set of a set $M$.
- $M_1\cong M_2$ is just an abbreviation for "there is a bijection from the set $M_1$ in the set $M_2$".

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please explain the notation. You can [edit] the post.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17152/when-2a-2b-implies-a-b-a-b-cardinals