# Automorphism group of a special commuting graph

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose $S_6$ is the symmetric group on six letters and let $X$ denote the  conjugacy class containing $(12)(34)$. Define a graph $\Gamma$ with vertex set $X$ and edges precisely the 2-element subsets of $X$ which commute as elements of $S_6$. I would like to know the automorphism group of the graph $\Gamma$.

P.S. These graphs are known in scientific texts as 'commuting graphs'.

Comment: An article worth pointing out in this context, despite the incorrect grammar in the article's title, seems to be Mahsa Mirzargar, Peter P. Pach, and A. R. Ashrafi: The automorphism group of commuting graph of a finite group. Bull. Korean Math. Soc. 51 (2014), No. 4, pp. 1145–1153. This article, however, seems not to contain a direct answer to OP: all results in loc. cit. are about commuting graphs *on a group in its entirety*, not on a conjugacy class, as in the OP. In particular, YCor's answer presently is the only answer known to me.

Comment: You meant to ask for *the isomorphism type of $U(\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma))$, described in usual group theoretic discourse*. In particular, by the formula for the cardinality of finite conjugacy classes, $\mathfrak{C}$ has cardinality $\frac{6!}{2^2\cdot 2! \ \cdot \ 1^2\cdot 2!} = 45$, so the $U(\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$ described above is a subgroup  of $\mathrm{Sym}(\text{$45$-element finite set})$, in other words, is a permutation group on 45 letters. In other words, your graph has 45 vertices. You probably essentially know this. I was just trying to correct my muddled comments of yesterday.

Answer (score 9):

It's an exercise to check it coincides with $\mathrm{Aut}(S_6)$ which has $S_6$ as subgroup of index 2.

Here are the steps. First, for arbitrary $n\ge 6$, consider the graph of transpositions. So this is the set $X_n$ of the $n(n-1)/2$ unordered pairs, with an edge between two whenever they are disjoint.

On $X_n$, consider the set $Y_n$ all unordered pairs of non-joined vertices (hence of the form $\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\}$ for $a,b,c$ pairwise distinct. There's a canonical map $\phi:Y_n\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ given by $\phi(\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\})=a$; we wish to show it's equivariant for the group action.

Link two elements of $Y_n$ if they are disjoint and contained no pair of joined vertices. Then any two linked elements of $Y_n$ have the same image by $\phi$ (check! this uses the disjointness assumption). Next consider the equivalence relation on $Y_n$ generated by this equivalence relation. The only 2-element subsets in $Y_n$ with same image by $\phi$ but not linked have the form, up to permutation, $\{\{12,13\},\{12,14\}\}$. But one indeed have $\{12,13\}-\{15,16\}-\{12,14\}$. So for $n\ge 6$, the equivalence relation on $Y_n$ generated by being linked consists of being in the same fibers of $\phi$, and hence the automorphism group of $X_n$ acts on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. This action is easily seen to be faithful. Since the permutation group $S_n$ already acts, this shows that the automorphism group of $X_n$ is $S_n$.

Next in $S_n$ for $n\ge 7$, the transpositions are the only elements whose centralizer has order $2(n-2)!$, i.e., form the only conjugacy class of order $n(n-1)/2$, and hence $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Comm}(S_n))$ stabilizes its subgraph $X_n$. Again a little argument shows that this action is faithful (i.e. an automorphism of $\mathrm{Comm}(S_n)$ fixing pointwise the transpositions is the identity; also for $n=6$.

For $n=6$ on the other hand, there are 2 conjugacy classes of order 15: transpositions and triple transpositions. They are switched by non-inner automorphisms. Hence the previous argument applies to the subgroup of index 2 of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Comm}(S_6))$ stabilizing $S_6$ and the result follows.

---

Update: my answer above was incomplete since it does not address double transpositions; let me now answer the question fully; this will actually make use of the above answer about the graph of transpositions!

Let us consider the graph $Z_n$ of **double transpositions**. Let me stick to $n=6$. I'll denote the permutation $(ab)(cd)$ as $(ab|cd)$ to avoid too many parentheses/commas.

In $Z_6$, there are triangles defined as follows:

1. Triangles of type I: $S_6$-permutes of the triangle $T_1=\{(12|34),(13|24),(14|23)\}$.
2. Triangles of type II: $S_6$-permutes of the triangles $T_2=\{(12|34),(12|56),(34|56)\}$.

It is straightforward that every triangle is of type I or type II, that the $S_6$-action preserves types of triangles, and that elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(S_6)\smallsetminus S_6$ exchange the two types. Consider the graph $W_6$ whose vertices are triangles in $Z_6$ and such that there is an edge between two triangles whenever they have a common vertex. For instance, there is an edge between $T_1$ and $T_2$ since they have the common vertex $(12|34)$. It is easy to check that $W_6$ is connected. Vertices of $W_6$ thus have type I or II, and we see that no vertices of the same type are joined. So $W_6$ is bipartite. Thus, for vertices of $W_6$, the relation "to have the same type" (which is not defined intrinsically) is indeed intrinsic, as it is equivalent to be at even distance. In particular, the isometry group $G$ of $W_6$ preserves the partition by types. Let $G'$ be its index 2 subgroup of type-preserving isometries. Define $W'_6$ as the graph consisting of vertices of type I in $W_6$, linked whenever they have distance at most 2 in $W_6$. We see that $W'_6$ is canonically isomorphic to the transposition graph! The isomorphism is given by mapping the triangle $T_1=\{(12|34),(13|24),(14|23)\}$ to $(56)$, etc.

By the previous result on $X_6$, we deduce that $G'=S_6$. It follows that $G$ is reduced to $\mathrm{Aut}(S_6)$ (since clearly an isometry of $W_6$ that is identity on vertices of type I has to be the identity). To conclude that $\mathrm{Aut}(Z_6)$ is reduced to $\mathrm{Aut}(S_6)$, it is enough to show that the canonical homomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(Z_6)\to\mathrm{Aut}(W_6)$ is injective. This is also immediate: for $f$ in the kernel, any double transposition belongs to exactly two triangles, i.e., two unordered triples of linked vertices, each of which is $f$-invariant, and hence is fixed by $f$. So we have proved that $\mathrm{Aut}(Z_6)$ is reduced to $\mathrm{Aut}(S_6)$, answering the original question.

Answer (score 6):

Easy enough

```
sage: G=SymmetricGroup(6)
sage: cc=G.conjugacy_class([2,2,1,1])
sage: gr=Graph([cc, lambda a,b: a*b==b*a and a!=b])
sage: gr.automorphism_group().cardinality()
1440
```

Comment: For inexperience users: "conjugacy_class(...)" makes Sage create the set of permutations in G which are conjugate to, e.g., the representative $(12)(34)$. Hopefully needless to say, this does not depend on the representative, only on the ordered partition of $6$, which is why the argument $[2,2,1,1]$, which corresponds to $2+2+1+1$, is used here. Moreover, the OP asked for the *structure* of this automorphism group, not only its order. I take the [GP wiki's word](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_1440) for it that there are a whopping 5958 isomorphism types of them.

Comment: So while this is certainly a nice and useful answer, one should remain aware of the following: (0) Sage's utterances are not mathematical proofs, (1) YCor's answer seems to be a correct mathematical proof and accomplishes quite a bit more than Sage here: YCor seems to have found the correct isomorphism type in the haystack of 5958 disctinct isomorphism types, (2) the initial 'Easy enough' is slightly grating (to me). I can understand how this happens (not being a native speaker), yet it seems to make this look easier than it actually is.

Comment: In this case knowing the order is enough - we know the outer automorphism group of $S_6$ acts on the graph, the only question is whether there is more. Second, I think anyone who wants to find the automorphism group of such a graph should automatically turn to a computer, and I suspect this may be part of F.C.'s motivation for the title of their answer.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: many thanks for pointing this out. The 'order taken together with context is enough to deduce the isomorphism type'-aspect was lost on me; it is interesting. I do not quite understand it though. I follow for a while, but not till the conclusion. Of course, from the definition of the OP's $\Gamma$ is is evident that $S_6\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$, so, as you say, the question remains whether there are more automorphisms. And of course, if we believe Sage's output, then seeing $1440=2\cdot 6! = 2\cdot\lvert S_6\rvert$ tells  us that there *are* more automorphisms. [...]

Comment: [...] So then we know that $\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$ is a finite group of order $1440$ containing $S_6$ as subgroup. Do we know anything more? Of course, by definition of 'automorphism group of a graph', we also known that *$\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$ is a permutation group on 45 letters*. (Since the graph in question has 45 vertices.) So we know $S_6\leq\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)\leq S_{45}$. But do we know anything more at this point? There seem to o be 5958 candidates still. I fear I am missing something obvious, yet I do not see why 'knowing the order is enough'. Could you please briefly explain why?

Comment: @PeterHeinig: In fact, $\operatorname{Aut}(S_6)$ acts on the graph, because the double transpositions are invariant under the automorphism group. To see this, note that the alternating group is invariant under $\operatorname{Aut}(S_6)$, as $A_6$ is the only normal subgroup of index $2$ in $S_6$, and the only elements of order $2$ in $A_6$ are just the double transpositions.

Comment: Another proof that $X$ is $\operatorname{Aut}(S_6)$-invariant: The elements in $X$ have centralizer of order $16$, the other involutions centralizer of order $48$.

Comment: @FriederLadisch: many thanks for the explanations. For the record: I *misread* Chris Godsil's comment. I read his comment "we know the outer automorphism group of $S_6$ acts on the graph", which *indeed sums up the gist of the issue* (though, pedantically speaking, one should say 'the outer automorphism group of $S_6$ acts **faithfully** on the *vertex set* of the graph') for the triviality 'we know that $S_6$ acts on the vertex set of the graph'. The latter (again: my misreading) does not contain enough information to justifiably say 'knowing the order is enough'.

Comment: For the record: the comment containing "For inexperience" I misspoke when saying "only on the integer partitions of $6$": **the right thing to say is just "partitions of $6$"**. What I said is wrong on more than one account: the usual technical term for "ordered partition" is *composition* (see e.g. Stanley's book on enumerative combinatorics); second, "the ordered partition" sounds like there were only *one* such partition; third, most seriously, saying "depends on the ordered partitions" sounds like as if, say, the number of conjugacy classes depended on how to order the partition.

Comment: @Ycor, thanks for the answer. I have confused. I think you have found automorphism group of a graph containing conjugacy class (12) not (12)(34)?

Comment: @maryam you're right (except that your comment is weirdly placed here) I've edited to complete my answer